# When using a URL that links to an MP3 stream, how do I convert it to a URI?

Tags: android, stream, uri, android-mediaplayer

I'm making an app that uses `MediaPlayer` to play internet radio streams.

Research online tells me that it's easiest to use a URI.

I was wondering how I convert this link to a URI?

The tutorial I found was a little confusing on this point: http://teamrock.planetwideradio.com:8000/teamrockhigh

Comment: Mind to share those "links" and "tutorial"? Why would it be easier by URI etc?

Answer (score 1):

Use the *[toURI](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#toURI())* method, which

> Returns the URI equivalent to this URL.

In your case:

```
URL url = new URL("http://teamrock.planetwideradio.com:8000/teamrockhigh"); 
URI uri = url.toURI();
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following error:
    
    
`Unhandled Exception: java.net.MalformedURLException`

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are using the link as an URL or maybe just a string. If you just look for a way to convert an URL to an URI then the code is rahter short:

```
// Convert a URL to a URI
URI uri = null;
URL url = null;
try{
  url = new URL("http://teamrock.planetwideradio.com:8000/teamrockhigh");
  uri = url.toURI();
}
catch (URISyntaxException e) {
// Exception handling
}
```

You can also use the string directly to create an URI object:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://teamrock.planetwideradio.com:8000/teamrockhigh");
```